# WordPress is not displaying photos correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

my WordPress page on some pages is showing src(unknown) like he can't take over from URL images. `Archive-shop.php` is not showing the photos but the `content-single-product` is showing and is pretty strange.

The photos are not local they are linked that is from a plugin BDroppy.

Here is the code from `archive-shop.php`

```php
foreach($unique_variations_ids as $vproduct_id):

  $vproduct = wc_get_product($vproduct_id);
                                
  $images_url = [];
  $imageUrl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($vproduct_id); 
  $attachment_ids = array_filter( array_map('intval', explode( ',', get_post_meta( $vproduct_id, '_wc_additional_variation_images', true ) ) ) );

  array_push($images_url, $imageUrl);
  foreach ($attachment_ids as $attachment_id) {
                                      
    // Display the image URL
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
    array_push($images_url, $image_url);
    // Display Image instead of URL
    // echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');
  }

  $imageUrlHover = $images_url[1];
  $column_width = 'normal';
  
  if(empty($_GET['orderby'])){
    $wide_variation_id = get_field('wide_variation_id', $parent_id);
      if($wide_variation_id == $vproduct_id){
        $column_width = strtolower(get_field('column_width', $parent_id));
      }                                     
  }
                                    
  $column_class = $column_width;

  // Your new HTML markup goes here
?>
                                    
  <li <?php wc_product_class( $column_class, $product ); ?>>
    <div class="product-inner"><div class="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>

    <!-- <div class="product-thumbnail portrait" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $permalink; ?>', '_blank');" data-product-id="<?php echo $vproduct_id; ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>');"> -->
    <div class="product-thumbnail portrait" data-product-id="<?php echo $vproduct_id; ?>">
    <?php 
      // Normal Gallery   
      echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '"><img class="original_image" src="' .$imageUrl. '"></a>';
      if($imageUrlHover != ''){
        echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '"><img class="hover_image" src="' .$imageUrlHover. '"></a>';
      } else {
        echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '"><img class="hover_image" src="' .$imageUrl. '"></a>';
      }

      // foreach ($images_url as $thumbnail){
      //     echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '"><img src="' .$thumbnail. '"></a>';
      // }
   ?>
   </div>

   <?php if($column_width == 'wide' && empty($_GET['orderby'])){ ?>
     <div class="product-thumbnail landscape" data-product-id="<?php echo $vproduct_id; ?>">
     <?php 
       $wide_images = get_field('wide_gallery');
       $size = 'full'; 
       if( $wide_images ):
         foreach( $wide_images as $wide_image_id ):
         // echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $wide_image_id, $size ) . '</a>';
           echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '"><img src="' .$wide_image_id. '"></a>';
         endforeach;
       endif;
     ?>
     </div>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php do_action('shop_wishlist'); ?>
</div>
```

Now there is content-single-page

```php-template
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery col-md-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-8 px-0 px-0" style="display: flex;-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;flex-wrap: wrap;margin-right: -15px;margin-left: -15px;">                          
    <div class="thumb-col-original col-md-12 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 px-0 px-0">
        <ul class="thumbnail-navigator">
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($images_url); $i++) { ?>
                <li class="thumbnail">
                    <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>-thumb" src="<?php echo $images_url[$i]; ?>" class="gallery-thumb-image">
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="full-image-col-original col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 px-0">
        
        
        <div id="lightgallery" class="full-image-container">
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($images_url); $i++) { ?>
                <a title="<?php echo $product_name . ' [' . ($i + 1) . '/' . count($images_url) . ']'; ?>" href="<?php echo $images_url[$i]; ?>">
                <!-- <a title="<?php echo $product_name . ' [' . $i . '/' . count($images_url) . ']'; ?>" href="<?php echo $images_url[$i]; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto"> -->
                    <!-- <img class="full-image image-zoom" data-zoom="<?php echo $images_url[$i]; ?>" id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>" src="<?php echo $images_url[$i]; ?>"> -->
                    <img class="full-image" id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>" src="<?php echo $images_url[$i]; ?>">
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

If is any fix for the problem or maybe how can I make WordPress take over from BDroppy photos.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzW6W.jpg